# Why commutator of positive and negative parts of scalar field is equal to the Feynman propagator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, commutator, greens-functions, correlation-functions, propagator

Peskin & Schroeder state that the contraction of two fields, defined as the commutator:
$$ [\phi^+(x),\phi^-(y)]\qquad \text{assuming}\ x^0>y^0$$
is equal to the Feynman propagator $D_F(x-y)$. But, why is that true?
If we take the definition of positive and negative frequency parts of the field:
$$\begin{aligned}
\phi^+(x) &= \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{\mathbf{p}}}}a_{\mathbf{p}}e^{-ip\cdot x}\\
\phi^-(x) &= \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{\mathbf{p}}}}a^\dagger_{\mathbf{p}}e^{+ip\cdot x}
\end{aligned}$$
And apply their commutator, we have:
$$\begin{multline}
[\phi^+(x),\phi^-(y)] = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{d^3p'}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{\mathbf{p}}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{\mathbf{p'}}}}e^{-ip\cdot x}e^{+ip'\cdot y}\underbrace{[a_{\mathbf{p}},a^\dagger_{\mathbf{p'}}]}_{=(2\pi)^3\delta^3(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{p'})}\\
=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2E_{\mathbf{p}}}e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}
\end{multline}$$
From here, I don't know how to go about getting the Feynman propagator. Any suggestion?

Comment: Isn't that explained in P&S p. 27-31?

Comment: So, if i understand it well, it is just a definition:
$$ \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2E_{\mathbf{p}}}e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)} = D_F(x-y)$$
But, as he says on page 83, why is that suppose to be equal to $\int \frac{d^{4} p}{(2 \pi)^{4}} \frac{i e^{-i p \cdot(x-y)}}{p^{2}-m^{2}+i \epsilon}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just evaluate the $p^0$ part of the integral. For $x^0>y^0$, we can close the contour below and enclose the pole at $p^0=E_\mathbf{p}$ (there's a pole at this point because $p$ is on-shell, so $p^2-m^2=0$). Then we evaluate the integral using [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), (I'm playing fast and loose with the $i\epsilon$)
$$\int \frac{d p^0}{2 \pi } \frac{ie^{-i p \cdot(x-y)}}{p^{2}-m^{2}+i \epsilon}=\int\frac{d p^0}{2 \pi i} \frac{-e^{-ip \cdot(x-y)}}{(p^0+\sqrt{m^{2}+\mathbf{p}^2})(p^0-\sqrt{m^{2}+\mathbf{p}^2})+i \epsilon}$$
$$=-\int\frac{d p^0}{2 \pi i} \frac{e^{-ip \cdot(x-y)}}{(p^0+E_\mathbf{p})(p^0-E_\mathbf{p})+i \epsilon}=\frac{e^{-ip \cdot(x-y)}}{2E_\mathbf{p}+i \epsilon},$$
where it's implicitly understood that $p^0=E_\mathbf{p}$ in the final $e^{-ip \cdot(x-y)}$. Note that a sign flip occurred because we're integrating clockwise instead of counterclockwise as assumed in Cauchy's integral formula. Using the above, we get (for $x^0>y^0$ only) that
$$\int \frac{d^{4} p}{(2 \pi)^{4}} \frac{i e^{-i p \cdot(x-y)}}{p^{2}-m^{2}+i \epsilon}=\int \frac{d^{3} p}{(2 \pi)^{3}} \frac{e^{-i p \cdot(x-y)}}{2E_\mathbf{p}+i \epsilon}.$$